# I need to recover a particular file which may be completely impossible to recover

Tags: data-recovery

I wrote a somewhat important essay in early January. Without going into too many specific details, I submitted this essay and assumed I wouldn't need this essay stored locally after I submitted it, so I deleted the file (.docx if file type is important here). As of right now, I realized it would be beneficial to have kept this file locally since then.

Some information:

- When I deleted the file, I was on Win11, now I am on an Ubuntu-based distribution
- I do not exactly remember whether I had kept the file in the windows 'recycle bin' or just deleted it permanently
- Between the time I deleted the file (Early Jan) and now I made a couple attempts to switch to the Linux distribution I am running currently, which obviously involves a number of formats which I think would significantly decrease the chances of ever finding this file again
- It would be quite difficult to contact and get this file back from the people I submitted the essay to (but not impossible) as there is a strong chance they deleted it from their systems.

Is there even a chance that this (.docx) file is not completely gone? More, generally, is it even possible to recover past the point of format?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems more like a Windows question as .docx is Windows format. If saved on NTFS partition whether Windows or shared NTFS may be better to use Windows tools. If in Linux partition you formatted & used multiple times very likely it is gone forever. Try this: https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n26s50ln705?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab&hl=en-us&gl=US Never used Windows tools, have used Photorec & it took forever & recovered many files, some partial files and copies of deleted older versions of files. Sorting thru them took even more time. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be completely unrelated to Linux; A Linux filesystem being written atop of that file is just one of several things that make the file unrecoverable.

Comment: Please do not vote to delete this! It is very much related to Linux, I would be attempt any recovery from a Linux distribution, I just need some help.

Comment: You have not said whether the disk partition that held your Windows data was deleted and overwritten by your Linux installs.  If the Linux installs were performed on a different disk partition than the one that held Windows, then you have a chance of recovering the file.  If the Linux installs went into the same disk partition as Windows, then they overwrote the Windows data and the file is not recoverable.

Answer (score 2):

It's gone!

3 months + some formats + new OS means that your chances are effectively zero (save for the remote possibility that a professional, and therefore costly, data recovery service might be able to salvage it).

Comment: Are you 100% sure?